# -a option in gradle

Tags: gradle

The following is from the [gradle docs](https://www.gradle.org/docs/current/userguide/tutorial_gradle_gui.html)

> The Task Tree context menu provides the following options:
>
> Execute ignoring dependencies. This does not require dependent
>   projects to be rebuilt (same as the -a option).

It's not clear what is the `-a` option? I tried to execute `gradle hl -a` for the following build script:

```
task helloapi {
    description = "Hello api"
}

task hl (dependsOn: 'helloapi'){
    println "Hl"
    description = "Hl"
}

helloapi << {
    println "Hello api"
}
```

But I got

```
Hl
:api:helloapi
Hello api
:api:hl
```

I thought the only way to exclude tasks depending on the target task is to use `-x` option. BTW, when I tryied to ran it in `gradle --gui` I got the following error:

```
Executing command: "api:hl-a"
Hl

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Project 'api' not found in project ':api'.

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.

BUILD FAILED

Total time: 6.751 secs
```

Is it a bug?

Comment: Where's `api` coming from? Could you make your example match reality?

Answer (score 0):

`-a` option ignores *project* dependencies - not *task* dependencies. Imagine that there's a complicated multimodule project. There was a change only in a single module (a task was changed) and You'd like to check if this task works well, when `-a` option is specified other module will not be rebuilt, just the changed one.

Comment: @St.Antario: is that what You were looking for?